# Calculate how far a ListView has been scrolled in pixels

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

Very simply, I have a requirement to calculate when a ListView has been scrolled (up or down) a certain number of *device* pixels.

For example, lets say my ListView is 1000 dp in height, how can I tell when the list has been scrolled at least 100 dp, or 1/10th the height of the ListView?

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to calculate the position within the list, i.e. if the list has 100 elements, and you're at position 10, 1/10th the height has been scrolled. Is this possible in your case?

Comment: @user184994: only if every element is the same height

Comment: @njzk2 Very good point, I didn't consider that.

Comment: you'll probably use getFirstVisiblePosition, then get the view, then the view should be able to tell you how it is positioned relatively to its parent

Comment: scratch that. `getScrollY` does that (in pixels. to obtain dp, use the factor in Resources or somewhere.)

Comment: @njzk2 is correct my rows have variable heights. If I use getFirstVisiblePosition() and then getScrollY() is this reliable? For example might it be the case that once scrolled off the screen that view gets recycled mid drag event?

Comment: the view at `getFirstVisiblePosition` is supposed to be always visible, so that should not be a problem. You can also use a scroll listener if you need for fine details.